# How to prove that a graph has a cycle?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Let **G= (V,E)** be a graph and **C** a loop in **G**.

Prove that there is a cycle in **G**.

Comment: I assume that you mean to say that $C$ is a closed walk instead of a loop (*a loop in the context of graph theory more commonly means an edge that has both end-points the same*) since otherwise this is either trivial (*if you allow cycles of length $1$*) or not enough to prove (*if you don't*).  If that were the case, then I further assume you mean to be talking about a closed walk *of odd length* since a closed walk of even length could simply be walking along the edges in one direction then reversing direction along those same edges and the graph itself is just a path or tree.

Comment: So, assuming we are talking about closed walks of odd length... see [proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Graph_containing_Closed_Walk_of_Odd_Length_also_contains_Odd_Cycle), or [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704054/graph-theory-if-a-graph-contains-a-closed-walk-of-odd-length-then-it-contains)... The biggest challenge to phrasing this correctly is deciding how to deal with repeated edges and reducing this to a problem involving a simpler closed walk with no repeated edges.

Comment: Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* What is the definition of a loop? What is the definition of a cycle?